# Question regarding percent hydration for 100% whole wheat bread dough

Tags: baking

Can someone suggest a typical hydration for strictly 100% whole wheat bread,
(no refined flour added). 
Since whole wheat absorbs more water,  I assume that for the
same weight dough as all-purpose flour,  it will require
a higher hydration,  but how much more?

Answer (score 6):

It depends a bit on how coarse or fine your wheat is ground.

With 75-85% you are in a pretty mainstream range - the equivalent of 65-75% hydration in white flour recipes.

If you work with longer or multi-step preparations (cold rise, bigga/levain/poolish methods, sourdough...), you can push it towards 100%, like for the no-knead-bread [here](https://www.jocooks.com/bakery/breads/no-knead-cast-iron-whole-wheat-bread/).

As a rule of thumb, go up by 10-15% when switching to whole wheat (less if mixing).

King Arthur flour supports this when writing

> The hydration (weight of water compared to flour) is 75% in this<sup>1</sup> recipe for No-Knead Crusty White Bread. But since whole wheat flour absorbs more liquid than all-purpose flour, we’re going to increase the hydration in this recipe to 85% to 90% or so.

in [their recipe](https://blog.kingarthurflour.com/2016/09/27/whole-wheat-no-knead-bread/) for whole wheat no-knead bread.

---

(<sup>1</sup> the original recipe with refined flour)

Comment: The range @Stephie suggested is also what is in the [Larousse of Bread](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Larousse-Book-Bread-Recipes-Make/dp/0714868876) for T150 flour (French equivalent of whole wheat). He suggests 360g water +  500g flour + 100g of 100% sourdough, so effectively ~75% hydration. Important to notice that this will lead to a fairly compact loaf though.

Comment: @greedyscholars yep. But 65% for refined is also on the compact side. And whole wheat is even worse when not hydrated properly. As one of our senior members says: "Wetter is better!" ;-)

Comment: Totally agree @Stephie!  But it took me a bit of experience to handle very wet doughs.  So I always prefer to be conservative when giving advice!